# How to paste multiline text in a contenteditable element so that each line is always in its own div?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Run the code and copy and paste any two lines of plain text into the box. It will paste the way I want, each line in its own div.

Now delete everything and press enter to create an empty div, then paste the text into that div. The unwanted behavior will be seen.

There's more examples of inconsistent behavior.
For example, delete everything and paste the text again. Now, select all and paste over the selection. It will behave like I want. Now, press enter to create a new div below the two existing ones, select all the text and paste it again. The unwanted behavior will be seen.

Some of the issues seem to do with the break tags generated. I have tried to work around it but one fix breaks something else.

```css
.text_area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2em 2em 2em 3em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.text_area>div {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin: 0.33em 0;
  min-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_area" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want each line to be in a `div`, you have to ensure that there is always a `div` for the content to go in.

Initialize your contenteditable element with an inner `div` to start. That ensures that when the user clicks in they'll already be in the correct environment.

Using JavaScript with an event listener on 'input' you can test if the contenteditable element becomes empty. You have to remember that `<br>` in the area would count as non-empty. This is what's causing your issues with enter. There's a `<br>` before the `<div>`s. If the innerHTML of your contenteditable area, excluding `<br>` and excess whitespace, then you need to append that `div` back as the child of the contenteditable area.

Lastly, you were getting `div` nesting when you were copying and pasting. That is because the default behavior of paste in a contenteditable area is to use HTML formatting. So if you copy `<div>a</div><div>b</div>` and paste it into `<div></div>` you'll get nesting. You can avoid this by getting only 'text/plain' from your clipboard instead.

```js
// Ensure Text is copied as plain text not as HTML (Fixes Nested Divs Problem)
document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.execCommand('inserttext', false, event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});

document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  // Remove All BR
  if (event.target.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for (let br of event.target.querySelectorAll('br')) {
      br.remove();
    }
  }

  // If DIV is ever made empty after removal of BRs
  if (event.target.innerHTML.trim().length === 0) {
    // Re-populate the initial DIV
    event.target.innerHTML = '';
    event.target.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  }
});
```

```css
.text_area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2em 2em 2em 3em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.text_area>div {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin: 0.33em 0;
  min-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Prime Your Content Editable Area With a DIV -->
<div class="text_area" contenteditable="true">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's almost there. Try this: type in a single character in the default child ```div```, then press ```backspace``` TWICE. Type in a single character again, then press ```backspace``` once. A ```br``` is created before the first child ```div``` and the cursor goes into the ```.text_area``` itself rather than a child ```div```.

Comment: Okay. There's some delay between the input event firing and appending the new child which allowed some typing to occur before the div appeared there. I've added a line to empty the div before appending the child to handle this case.

Comment: If you press backspace, then enter a single character, then select all, the press enter, a <br> ocurrs at the top again.

I think I fixed it with this at the bottom of your code:


```if (event.target.firstElementChild?.localName === "br") {
event.target.firstElementChild.remove();
}```


Or maybe I could do this after your code:


```[...event.target.querySelectorAll('br')].forEach(br => br.remove()); console.log(event.target.outerHTML);```


What do you think?

Comment: That seems to work pretty well. Updated to include the `br` removal, and fix the second condition to no longer string replace the `<br>` since that's handled separately. I made a slight modification. Since you want every line to be in it's own div. `br` should _never_ appear in the editable area. Since everything is in it's own div.

Comment: Do you know an alternative to  ```document.execCommand('inserttext'...```? Just curious because even though execCommand still works, it's deprecated.

Comment: The [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) define some new options. However, this particular problem would be very tedious to solve with selection and ranges because you'd have to processes and place every element yourself if you wanted text with line breaks to appear in separate divs, rather than collapsed into a single one.